# Why does private lateinit var mCustomAdapter CustomAdapter cause Property getter or setter expected in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The code `mRecyclerView.adapter= CustomAdapter(allList)`  works well, I hope to define a private var mCustomAdapter, and assign value late.

But the code `private lateinit var mCustomAdapter CustomAdapter`  cause error, how can I fixed it? Thanks!

**Code A**

```
class UIMain : AppCompatActivity() {


    private lateinit var mCustomAdapter CustomAdapter  //Error

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main)

        ...

        mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)
        mRecyclerView.adapter= CustomAdapter(allList) //OK

    }
```

**Code B**

```
class CustomAdapter (val backupItemList: List<MSetting>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var mSelectedItem = -1

    //this method is returning the view for each item in the list
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_recyclerview, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(v)
    }


    fun getSelectedItem():Int{
        return  mSelectedItem
    }

    //this method is binding the data on the list
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(backupItemList[position])
        holder.itemView.radioButton.setChecked(position == mSelectedItem);
    }

    //this method is giving the size of the list
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return backupItemList.size
    }

    //the class is hodling the list view
    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bindItems(aMSetting: MSetting) {

            //itemView.radioButton.isChecked=false

            itemView.radioButton.tag=aMSetting._id
            itemView.textViewUsername.text=aMSetting.createdDate.toString()
            itemView.textViewAddress.text=aMSetting.description

            itemView.radioButton.setOnClickListener {
                mSelectedItem=getAdapterPosition()
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `:` at the end of `mCustomAdapter` variable

Try this:

```
private lateinit var mCustomAdapter: CustomAdapter
```

See more: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#defining-variables